# Can not load the dist files when I run `index.html` in browser

Tags: webpack, vue.js

After I `npm run build` generate the dist files, I run the `index.html`, all the resources files can not load:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (main.1f51eed1059b282ae3ed.css, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (main.1f51eed1059b282ae3ed.js, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (vendors.1f51eed1059b282ae3ed.js, line 0)
[Error] Did not load script at 'http://localhost:63342/dist/vendors.1f51eed1059b282ae3ed.js' because non script MIME types are not allowed when 'X-Content-Type: nosniff' is given.
[Error] Did not load script at 'http://localhost:63342/dist/main.1f51eed1059b282ae3ed.js' because non script MIME types are not allowed when 'X-Content-Type: nosniff' is given.
```

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

My dist files:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

my `webpack.base.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/main',
    vendors: './src/vendors'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.vue$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'vue-loader',
          options: {
            loaders: {
              less: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                use: ['css-loader?minimize', 'autoprefixer-loader', 'less-loader'],
                fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
              }),
              css: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                use: ['css-loader', 'autoprefixer-loader', 'less-loader'],
                fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
              })
            }
          }
        },
          {
            loader: 'iview-loader',
            options: {
              prefix: false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /iview\/.*?js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: ['css-loader?minimize', 'autoprefixer-loader'],
          fallback: 'style-loader'
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [{
          loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
        }, {
          loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
        }, {
          loader: "less-loader" // compiles Less to CSS
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|jpg|png|woff|svg|eot|ttf)\??.*$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=1024'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(html|tpl)$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
    alias: {
      'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': path.resolve('src')
    }
  }
};
```

my `webpack.prod.config.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const webpackBaseConfig = require('./webpack.base.config.js');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.open('./src/config/env.js', 'w', function (err, fd) {
  const buf = 'export default "production";';
  fs.write(fd, buf, 0, buf.length, 0, function (err, written, buffer) {
  });
});

module.exports = merge(webpackBaseConfig, {
  output: {
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[hash].chunk.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[hash].css',
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendors',
      filename: 'vendors.[hash].js'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: './index.html',
      template: './src/template/index.ejs',
      inject: false
    })
  ]
});
```

---

I am not sure whether is caused by the configuration, who can tell me why I can not load the dist files when I run the dist `index.html` in browser?

---

the url in the browser:

```
http://localhost:63342/wx_backup/dist/index.html?_ijt=gutju68tikagu6rldhshoenmrv
```

I also tried:

```
http://localhost:63342/wx_backup/dist/index.html
```

Comment: Are you running a web server or do you open the index.html via file:///?

Comment: @LassiUosukainen right click -> Run 'index.html'

Comment: What is the content of the url bar when you are "running" index.html?

Comment: @LassiUosukainen `http://localhost:63342/wx_backup/dist/index.html?_ijt=gutju68tikagu6rldhshoenmrv`

Answer (score 3):

I guess you created this project via **vue-cli**, you might not noticed there was a tip after you completed **npm run build** command.

> Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.
>     Opening index.html over file:// won't work.

So for developing, just need to use **npm run dev** or **npm run start** to debug and hot reload.

As for production release, you'd better put the dist files to a static file server such as Nginx, Apach, IIS or even hosted via **express** static file middleware.

Answer (score 2):

From the configuration that you have posted, I assume that you are using the `vuejs-template/webpack` template, you can configure the following to run `index.html` in the browser. I would still recommend using a HTTP server over opening `index.html` locally.

### config.js

```
build: {
  // other default code

  assetsPublicPath: ''
}
```

### routes.js

```
export default new Router({
  base: window.location.pathname
  // your other code here
})
```

Firefox and Safari will work with `mode: 'history'`. To make it work on Chrome, just remove history mode.

**UPDATE 2020**
For the current Vue version it is the file `vue.config.js` and the option is called `publicPath`:

> The value can also be set to an empty string ('') or a relative path
>   (./) so that all assets are linked using relative paths. This allows
>   the built bundle to be deployed under any public path, or used in a
>   file system based environment like a Cordova hybrid app.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same issue. I was able to fix the issue by pointing my flask server to distribution folder as below:

```
app = Flask(__name__,template_folder="./dist/",static_folder="./dist/static")
```

Different kinds of servers can have their own directory structure requirements. Flask server, for instance, looks for **index.html** file in the **Templates** folder and all the static assets under **Static** folder and expects the following directory structure by default:

```
static/
     js/
        bundle.js
     css/
templates/
        index.html
server.py
```

In my case, however, the structure was:

```
dist/
   index.html
   static/
         js/
            bundle.js
         css/ 
src/
build/
server.py
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I updated "**base**" element href="./"  in index.html then problem resolved

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your folders doesn't match the urls.

In this case, you should be able to reach the js bundles with the following url:

```
http://localhost:63342/wx_backup/dist/vendors.1f51eed1059b282ae3ed.js
```

The url in your index.html file is missing a part of the folder structure, so it can't be found.

The problem can be solved without any configuration changes. It just means you need to change the folder structure of your files. The js bundles need to be in a dist folder relative to the index.html file. If you have the following folder structure and run your webserver here it works as expected.

```
index.html
dist
    js bundles here
```

Comment: but whether there is a way for the correct config to `npm run build` to generate the correct file paths?

Comment: no, I tried pull the index.html outter a directory, there is no error in index.html now, but in the other page, there will gets other import errors.

Comment: @sof-03 It works that way if you run your webserver on the same folder as index.html. Now your webserver serves the parent folder of where index.html is, so the path has /wx_backup/ in it.